# Terminal broken? (Mac)

Tags: 12.10, laptop, mac, usb-drive

In Terminal (Mac) when I do step 9 (sudo dd if=//Users/neilatkin/Desktop/ubuntu.img of=/dev/disk1 bs=1m (replace /path/to/downloaded.img with the path where the image file is located; for example, ./ubuntu.img or ./ubuntu.dmg)), when I press enter then enter the password to the mac it just has white underneath it and after it does nothing when I enter in commands. To get it to work again I have to close it and re-open it. I'm pretty sure that I'm using the correct file from my desktop too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` outputs nothing and takes a while to run.  Give it ten minutes and see if it finishes.

Comment: OK, so now it's saying 'Resource busy'

Comment: unmount (eject) the drive before executing the command.

Comment: When I unmount it and then do the command it just goes back to what it did before; just giving me nothing

Comment: Did you wait a full ten minutes?  The dd command does not give any output

Comment: OK, so after about 10 minutes it comes out with                  753+1 records in
753+1 records out
789884928 bytes transferred in 610.902524 secs (1292980 bytes/sec) but in disk utility it says the usb has been damaged

Comment: Noting that USB booting doesn't work normally on apple hardware, can you boot from the USB drive?

Comment: It's done now - booted it from a windows PC that I borrowed from my brother.